# Why submit button is not enabled immediately on change to textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this code The button will become enabled only after:

1. I type something in textfield
2. I change the focus out of the textfield.

How can I get the button to enable as soon as something is typed in?

```html
  function validateAmount(){
    if ($('#parlay-amount-textfield').val().length > 0) {
        $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    validateAmount();
    $('#parlay-amount-textfield').change(validateAmount);
  });
```

Comment: its there typo in post

Comment: Instead of waiting for the "change" event, wait for "keypress".

Comment: The buttons and textfield have the proper id's. The submit button does change but only after I change the focus out of the textfield

Comment: Actually use "input" as suggested by Mr. Crowder; you could wait for both "input" *and* "keypress" to deal with old browsers that don't do "input" events (IE8) or that are a little broken (IE9).

Comment: keypress not working @Pointy

Comment: keypress does not work because it doesn't disable on change. But that is still helpful

Comment: @slindsey3000: Yes, with `keypress` (or `keydown`, so you half-handle paste on browsers that don't provide `input` **or** `paste`) you have to check for changes *after* the event is done being processed, I've shown how in my answer.

Comment: oh right, again see Mr. Crowder's solution - the "keypress" event (and all the "key" events) fire *before* the input value is updated. His solution uses a brief time delay to let the default action complete before checking the value status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event doesn't fire until focus leaves the `input` field.

You can use the `input` event instead on modern browsers, which fires immediately. Or a combination of events to support slightly older browsers: `input change paste click` which you can respond to immediately and then `keydown` which you need to respond to after a very brief delay. But I think `input`'s support is very good these days, with the notable exception of IE8 which doesn't support it.

Example with just `input`:

```js
function validateAmount() {
  if ($('#parlay-amount-textfield').val().length > 0) {
    $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  validateAmount();
  $('#parlay-amount-textfield').on("input", validateAmount);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="parlay-amount-textfield">
<input type="button" id="parlay-submit-button" value="Send">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example with `input change paste click` handled immediately and `keydown` after a very brief delay:

```js
function validateAmount() {
  if ($('#parlay-amount-textfield').val().length > 0) {
    $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  validateAmount();
  $('#parlay-amount-textfield')
    .on("input change paste click", validateAmount)
    .on("keydown", function() {
      setTimeout(validateAmount, 0);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="parlay-amount-textfield">
<input type="button" id="parlay-submit-button" value="Send">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Side note: FWIW, `validateAmount` can be a bit shorter:

```
function validateAmount() {
  $("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", $('#parlay-amount-textfield').val().length == 0);
}
```

And if just spaces isn't a valid value, you might consider throwing a `$.trim()` around `$('#parlay-amount-textfield').val()` (or on modern browsers, using `$('#parlay-amount-textfield').val().trim()`).

Comment: Single line `$("#parlay-submit-button").prop("disabled", $('#parlay-amount-textfield').val().length === 0);` And `trigger()` `$('#parlay-amount-textfield').on("input", validateAmount).trigger('input');`

Answer (score 0):

```
Since we are using the change event the input fields focus tends to say that user has not yet ended up his field with data.so only after the focus is moved the button gets enabled u can use the above Link for further clarifications
[1]"https://jsfiddle.net/MuthuramanNagarajan/gs2sff6j/"
```